# R h2o.glm error - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32

Tags: r, h2o

I am attempting to run h2o.glm in R but am encountering some strange behaviour. The same line of code sometimes works and sometimes errors with the following result

```
h2o.glm(x = Predictors.Revised, y = "NN", model_id = "GLM_FREQ_INITIAL", 
offset_column = "Offset.To.Apply", nfolds = 5, family = "poisson", 
link = "log", lambda_search = TRUE, training_frame = TrainDS.h2o, 
alpha = 1, standardize = TRUE)
```

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32  at
>   water.util.ArrayUtils.subtract(ArrayUtils.java:1334)  at
>   hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.fitIRLSM(GLM.java:824)  at
>   hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.fitModel(GLM.java:1080)     at
>   hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.computeSubmodel(GLM.java:1169)  at
>   hex.glm.GLM.cv_computeAndSetOptimalParameters(GLM.java:132)   at
>   hex.ModelBuilder.cv_buildModels(ModelBuilder.java:595)    at
>   hex.ModelBuilder.computeCrossValidation(ModelBuilder.java:431)    at
>   hex.glm.GLM.computeCrossValidation(GLM.java:100)  at
>   hex.ModelBuilder$1.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:309)    at
>   water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1395)  at
>   jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)  at
>   jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)    at
>   jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)     at
>   jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)    at
>   jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)

- R Version: 3.3.1
- Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
- h2o Version: 3.22.1.5

Any ideas why? I am stumped.

Comment: hi adrian, could you provide a fully reproducible code snippet so that we can test out what you did? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you get an "out of bounds" error (e.g. `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`), you should check if there is anything you are iterating over, during multiple runs of your glm function. To help debug the issue I would remove all but the simplest arguments and then slowly add arguments in while running whatever set of steps led to the issue, until you can identify the parameter that is causing the out of bounds error.